# I'm getting "Error 403" when installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

I'm trying to install rails -v 5.2.2 on wsl ubuntu 18.04.
Im met with following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Forbidden 403 (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/nokogiri-1.13.3-x64-unknown.gemspec.rz)
```

I'm relatively new to bash and I'm not sure what to do at this point, as google failed me. Help? :)

Comment: How do you install it?

Comment: HTTP error 403 is "unauthorized" access. Are you on a network that might block traffic (or block it to Rubygems) or even non-web traffic like some public, but restricted, WiFi networks? Is your WSL configured to firewall traffic?

Comment: @rcarba I am installing it using command `sudo gem install rails -v 5.2.2`

Comment: @Unixmonkey I guess that may be the problem and unfortunately Im not allowed to turn off the restrictions. Is there a way to somehow go around it? maybe downloading it from different source or on different machine and copying?

Comment: @Egilzzz Sure, you could run the install from a less restrictive network, or you could try downloading the individual gems and installing them from files like `gem install gemname.gem`. If you are on a restrictive work network with a legit business need you can ask about a mirror repository like JFrog Artifactory or a private gemserver.

Comment: @Unixmonkey I managed to install it by copying gem from other machine and using the `gem install gemname.gem`
Thank you a lot :D

Comment: Although now, although `gem list --local rails` shows only version 5.2.2, `rails -v` shows me version 7.0.2.2

Comment: @Egilzzz you can have multiple versions of the Rails gem installed, but the `rails` command is generally a "binstub" pointing to a certain version. You can either uninstall that version with `gem uninstall rails` (it'll ask you which version), or you can use the older generators like `rails _5.2.2_ new myAppName`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue with `-v 5.2.3`. What worked for me was updating RubyGems with:

```
gem update --system
```

Then again:

```
gem install rails --version 5.2.3
```

and no issues this time.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: As proposed by @Unixmonkey downloading the gem on separate machine with no restrictions and copying the gemfile worked.

Solution 2: Installing ruby through RVM and trusting its certificates

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).